# Changing PyQT Table Item from QComboBox to QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

In my PyQT window, I have a table containing `QComboBox` in one column. How can the `QComboBox` later be changed to the regular `QTableWidgetItem` to display some text?

I tried the following but the `QComboBox` was not replaced by text from `QTableWidgetItem`.

```
myTable= QTableWidget()
myTable.setRowCount(6)
myTable.setColumnCount(2)
myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Name;Age;").split(";"))
myTable.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


# Populate with QComboBox in column 1
for i, name in enumerate(nameList):
    myTable.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(name ))

    ageCombo = QComboBox()
    for option in ageComboOptions:
        ageCombo.addItem(option)
    myTable.setCellWidget(i, 1, ageCombo)

# Change column 1 to QTableWidgetItem
for i, name in enumerate(nameList):
    myTable.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(name))
```

Comment: Did you intend that the combo-box is only there for *editing* the text in the cell? So after the user selects an item, the combo-box shoud disappear and the cell gets updated with the new text?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that if you just `removeCellWidget` you'll get what you want.  Example code below.

But in more detail:

The "Item" as set by `setItem` and the "Widget" as set by `setCellWidget` are different - they play different roles.  The item carries the data for the cell: in the model view architecture it's in the model.  The widget is doing the display: it's in the view.  So, when you set the cell widget you might still expect it to use an item in the model behind it.  However, the `QTableWidget` provides a simplified API to the full model view architecture as used in QT (e.g. see the `QTableView` and `QAbstractitemModel`).  It provides its own default model which you access via an item for each cell.  Then, when you replace the widget on a cell it dispenses with any item at all and just allows you to control the widget directly. Remove the widget and it goes back to using the item.

Here's a working example:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.myTable= QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.myTable.setRowCount(1)
        self.myTable.setColumnCount(2)

        item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("a")
        self.myTable.setItem(0, 0, item1)
        item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("b")
        self.myTable.setItem(0, 1, item2)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.myTable)

        menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.setMenuBar(menubar)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(menubar)
        menu.setTitle("Test")
        action = QtGui.QAction(self)
        action.setText("Test 1")
        action.triggered.connect(self.test1)
        menu.addAction(action)
        action = QtGui.QAction(self)
        action.setText("Test 2")
        action.triggered.connect(self.test2)
        menu.addAction(action)
        menubar.addAction(menu.menuAction())


        self.show()

    def test1(self):
        self.myTable.removeCellWidget(0, 1)

    def test2(self):
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.addItem("c")
        combo.addItem("d")
        self.myTable.setCellWidget(0, 1, combo)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cut down". `QTableWidget` is a subclass of `QTableView`, and its model is a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`. As the Qt docs says, it's "an item-based table view with a default model". A `QTableWidgetItem` is really just a convenience API for manipulating the data in the model.

Comment: Yes - that wasn't clear.  Hopefully improved wording?

Comment: It's not simplified - quite the opposite in fact. It's a generic convenience class that saves you the trouble of writing your own custom model/view subclasses (using the exact same architecture). It also adds a whole *extra* layer to give you an item-based API. For example, the `QTableWidget.setCellWidget` function is an item-based wrapper around `QAbstractItemView.setIndexWidget`.

Comment: Right it's not simplified in the sense that it is extra but the API it provides is simpler.  Otherwise it wouldn't add any convenience.  But if you can re-phrase I'm probably happy to accept your edits.  Also what do you mean "item-based"?  Do you just mean row,cell rather than Index?

Comment: I think I may have mis-read your edits slightly. But FWIW, I meant convenient in the sense that you don't have to make it yourself. By "item-based", I meant the data is accessed via a specialized item class, rather than getting it directly from the model via an index.

Comment: OK cool - I just wanted to say how the `QTableWidget` API, by eliding the model view distinction, makes it easier to confuse the item with the widget, as the OP did.